# получить адрес из инструкции "call"

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Потихоньку изучаю ассемблер и пытаюсь разобраться в отладке своей программы, поиском уязвимостей и т.д.

Проблема в следующем, при просмотре программы в дизассемблере, есть инструкция по адресу 0x11BC132 , выглядит она так

`call test.exe+CBB18`

Вот как мне программно получить этот адрес "test.exe+CBB18"? Пробовал так:

```
DWORD call = *(DWORD*)0x11BC132
```

Нечего не вышло, думаю здесь нужна асм-вставка, помогите пожалуйста оформить ее, так как в "асм" не силен, по возможности, подскажите как обойтись без асм вставок, так как асм-вставки не работают в х64. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Покажите сишный код, для которого генерится этот `call`. И объясните, почему не хотите воспользоваться обычным указателем на функцию, если "программно получить" нужно из тех же исходников. Если не из тех же, то про use case подробней.

Comment: @Pink Tux - я смотрю на это дело со стороны "взломщика", а у него не будет под рукой моего исходника, будет только дамп в дизассемблированном виде

Comment: Взломщик воспользуется какой-нибудь IDA Pro и не будет забивать себе голову несущественными деталями :) Или прочитает про формат исполняемых файлов и работу с relocation table... В общем, конечная задача непонятна.

Comment: @Pink Tux - конечная задача и начальная задача и вообще смысл моего вопроса - получить адрес который в инструкции call, средствами с++, а то что может и не может взломщик - это все второстепенно лично для меня, в данный момент мне важно получить адрес

Comment: Да неважно чем адрес получать: средствами C++, C, перла или бейсика. Алгоритм везде одинаков, отправные точки я назвал: гуглить про "формат PE" и "relocation table". Для затравки: https://habrahabr.ru/post/266831/ плюс ссылки в конце статьи.

Comment: @Pink Tux - мне важно средствами с++, так как я не знаю других языков программирования

Comment: Адрес в `call` на самом деле относительный. А программа при запуске может быть размещена в памяти по разным адресам, поэтому статически - только по коду в экзешнике - вы фактический адрес никак не определите. Если вам нужно встроить какой-то код в экзешник, потом перенаправить `call`, тут опять же нужно будет вставлять относительный адрес (разница между адресом команды идущей после `call` и вызываемым кодом). Т.к. адрес перехода относительный, то таблица релокаций тут ни при чем (это к комментарию Pink Tux).

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос - как вы хотите потом этот адрес использовать - тогда может что-то смогу подсказать.

Comment: @insolor - да мне пока что просто получить нужно этот адрес, я ожидал ответ типа DWORD getCallAdr(){__asm{move eax, 0x11BC132 ; call eax; retn}}(знаю что написал бред, это просто пример), дальше буду думать как защитить определенный участок кода, но это уже другая история...

Comment: @Duracell, смотря что там за код в этой функции. Если там проверка серийника, например, то вам нужно "защищать" и саму функцию, и вызывающий код. Можно воткнуть проверку в нескольких местах программы, делать ее разными способами. Можно использовать "навесной" протектор (на всю программу). Все это усложнит жизнь крэкеру, но не исключит возможность взлома.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Для 32-битного приложения**

Команда call имеет опкод `E8 + delta (4b)`, где `delta = to - (from + 5)`

`from` - адрес команды call

`to` - адрес вызываемой функции

```
const size_t from = 0x11BC132;
int delta = *(int*)((unsigned char*)from + 1); // приведение к unsigned char* нужно, если арифметика типа from отличается от стандартной
size_t to = from + delta + 5;
```

Чтобы преобразовать `call something` в `call test.exe + something_else`, нужно вычесть из `something` так называемый `image_base`. Для типичных 32-битных PE он равняется **0x400000**. То есть в Вашем случае адрес функции с большой вероятность равен **0x4CBB18**.

---

**Для 64-битного приложения**

Команда `call` может иметь аналогичный вид, если `delta <= 0xFFFFFFFF`, поэтому можно проверять следующим образом:

```
const size_t from = 0x11BC132;
if (*((unsigned char *)from) == 0xE8)
{
    int delta = *(int*)((unsigned char*)from + 1);
    size_t to = from + delta + 5;
}
```

Крайне сомневаюсь, что delta может превысить 2 гигабайта, поэтому можно использовать этот вариант (даже без `if`, если уверены, что это `call`)

Comment: спасибо, четкий ответ, если есть возможность привести пример для х64, то пожалуйста, если нет то нет, еще раз огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @Duracell не сразу увидел, что вопрос про x64, поэтому дополнил тем, что только что проверил в отладчике